# How do I get Http Header of calling API from a WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two WebApi (.NET Core) application e.g. WebApi1 and WebApi2. Now I am calling/consuming WebApi1 (endpoint) from WebApi2. How do I get WebApi1 Http Header values from WebApi2 application?

Tried with Request.Header; but did not get WebApi1 headers. Here is the code written in controller action -

```
                    (Request?.Headers ?? throw new Exception("Http Header is Null")).ToDictionary<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>, string, string>(
                        header => header.Key, header => header.Value);
```

here I am getting WebApi2 header.

Comment: Can you also provide the code you tried to get the header ? Not just the Request.Header instruction, the relevant parts of the method.

Comment: @Skrface - code added

Comment: Are you sure you actually send any headers?

Comment: Yes I am sending from WebApi1, from Fiddler I verified.

Comment: @DebasisGhosh `Request.Headers.GetValues(string name)`?

Comment: @bolkay - tried but did not get exact http headers what I have set in WebApi1. and  I want all values in Header.

Comment: Post the code where you pass the headers.  Otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Comment: What is `Request?.Headers`? How did you call web api1 from api2?

Answer (score 1):

For calling web api1 from api2, you could try `HttpClient` like:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    public ValuesController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    }
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> Get()
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44349/api/values");
        var headers = response.Headers.ToList();
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

And register the `HttpClient` by

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed "Enable CORS" in my application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

```
options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                "http://www.contoso.com")
                                **.AllowAnyHeader()**
                                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
```

here "AllowAnyHeader" required to pass custom header. Now I am able to capture custom http header.